# Postresql & Access synchronising

Tags: postgresql, replication, ms-access

I would like to ask for hints / tips / pointers on the possible approaches that I might use for the following...

I maintain a database locally using postgresql 9.5, hosted on a Linux server.
However, I now find myself needing to keep a subset of this data in sync with a MS Access Jet/ACE database (specifically, a 64-bit MDE file with MDW user level security created under Access 2010). There is an air-gap between these two systems, and the flow of data is predominately one-way from postgres to access.

What options do I have, and what caveats / pitfalls do I need to beware of please? I have the ODBC driver installed, and can see all the data on the postgres server. So 'pulling' the data from postgres into access would be one approach. But my VBA is not great, and I would prefer in many ways to work under Linux with bash/perl/python/sed/awk/etc. I would also prefer, if possible, to produce a means of transferring only the changes in each table, rather than the whole contents. I'm quite happy to work with two solutions, one for each direction of data-flow. However, migrating to a MSSQL server is not an option.

Many thanks.

Comment: **So 'pulling' the data from postgres into access would be one approach. But my VBA is not great** So where did you get stuck?

Comment: So far, I've not got stuck. I am at planning stage, and considering potential options, and hopefully avoiding a situation where I blindly take one road, then find myself in 6 months' time regretting a decision made in ignorance. I suppose this is less of a "how can I..." question, and more of a "how should I do it" one, and understanding the pros/cons of each option.